# C if-statement parentheses with isnan macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

In C, I used to be able to use the `isnan` macro without parentheses in an `if` condition, like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    float x,y,z;
    x=0; y=0; z=x/y;  
    if isnan(z) {            // <--- no parens around isnan
        printf("z isnan!");
    }
}
```

This compiles on Ubuntu 15.10 with gcc 5.2.1-22ubuntu2.

However, on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with gcc 4.7.4-3ubuntu12, I get this gcc compiler error:

```
error: expected '(' before '__builtin_isnan'
```

**What compiler flag allows me to omit parentheses in an `if` condition?**

Comment: No, the compiler will not let you omit parentheses around an `if` statement, although they can be supplied by the (preprocessor) macro. Your code works fine in MSVC, where (see next comment) `isnan` is a macro *in C only*.

Comment: isnan is defined as a macro in some versions, and as a function in others. in c99 it is a macro, so omitting the parenthesis may work since it should be parenthesized (as in the example of @WeatherVane). maybe `-std=c99` would work.

Comment: Ref the comment from @A.S.H I edited my earlier one, which did say: That might depend on how you implement it. In MSVC I can have `#define TEST(x) (a==x)` and then `int a = 1; if TEST(1) printf("Yes\n");` and no parentheses were required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No compiler flag will permit that.

The compiler (or, more likely, a header file) in your implementation where it worked probably defined `isnan()` as a macro in enclosing parentheses, such as

```
 #define isnan(_x) (__builtin_isnan(_x))
```

Which would have a side-effect of permitting the behaviour you have used.

However, the definition of `isnan()` is implementation defined, so (among other things) is not required to be a macro enclosed in parentheses.

You would be better off, practically, of putting all of your usages of `if isnan(x)` with `if (isnan(x))`.   This will guarantee your code works, even if your compiler or standard library is updated, or if your code is ported to another (C99 or later) compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, how would I find the definition of `isnan`?

Comment: Look in the header `<math.h>` that comes with your compiler.   It will probably be a file named `math.h` in the include path used by your compiler.   For gcc, look at [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html). If there are `#include` directives in that file, look in the named files ....     NOTE:  I strongly advise against editing standard header files, since they may be overwritten any time your compiler/library is updated.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. The file `/usr/include/math.h` defines `isnan` pretty much as you described in your answer.